# SelectionChanged showing the old value

Tags: c#, wpf

The SelectionChanged event on a ComboBox still appears to display the old value.  I need the get the value that it is being changed to.  Any ideas?.

Currently on the XAML code I use:

```
SelectionChanged="TxtProductFamily_SelectionChanged"
```

C#

```
private void TxtProductFamily_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show(TxtProductFamily.Text);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code how you get new selection value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `AddedItems` within the `EventArgs`.

```
private void TxtProductFamily_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var addedItem in e.AddedItems)
    {
        var item = addedItem as String; // <-- Cast to whatever type here, string, ViewModel, int, etc.
        if (item != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What collection type are you binding to? If it's a Collection of Strings, you need to cast it first before you Show it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need accurate information on what has been selected/unselected then [`Selector.SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event gives you `SelectionChangedEventArgs` as a parameter from which you can get 2 lists

[`AddedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.addeditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which

> Gets a list that contains the **items that were selected**.

and [`RemovedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.removeditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which

> Gets a list that contains the **items that were unselected**.

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox.Text Updated after the ComboBox.SelectionChange event fired.

Obtain the value by ComboBox.SelectedItem \ ComboBox.SelectedValue.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow you.